# How to Increase bandwith in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bandwidth

I set up a website in google cloud with the basic level (or perhaps not basic but second level) of bandwidth which if I am not mistaken should allow for about 30,000. plus visits. Its been working ok for the last 8 days. This website is a news site so today they published something and their google stats read something on the order of 150,000 visits to this one article which crashed the site.

I do not know where to change this cnfiguration now. My question is where or how do I change the configuration to INCREASE bandwidth??? Thanks ! Much appreciated!

Comment: Google Cloud does not have "network levels" which means you cannot increase or decrease bandwidth. Which service are you using? Some services have limitations due to memory, CPUs, quotas, etc. Edit your question with details.

Comment: On which GCP product is your website deployed? And which size of instance are you using

Comment: In which region is deployed your app?